# compare an array that is inputted by user to an array thats in a mysql table then display results if at least one element of the arrays match?

Tags: php, html, mysql

For my current project, I have a page where users can upload links along with "tags" to further classify the links.  It is for playlists, so an example would be: url: https://apple.music.com, tags: Drake, Big Sean, Hip Hop, .  Then, people can search for playlists by inputting desired tags, such as "Lil Wayne, J Cole, Rap, ".  If at least one of the desired tags match one of the uploaded tags, then the url of the matching tag is echoed.  By the way, the users input tags by typing in a few letters and then a JQuery function auto-finishes it to add a comma and a space after each tag.  That list of tags is then turned into an array which is stored in the mysql table.  I know this may be a little vague, but any help is great!

Comment: so what you want?

Comment: it says it in the title

Comment: Instead of storing tags as CSV in one column, consider setting up a separate tags table, and a many-to-many relationship between URLs and tags. Then you will be able to select URLs with tags matching your set of tags with a simple IN expression.

Comment: Ok, I understand the many-to-many relationship, but what would the IN expression look like?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: yes, that's perfect.  thank you!